# Friedman Test not significant but Post Hoc Tests are?

Tags: friedman-test

I am running a Friedman test to find out if there are differences in a ranking between 4 treatments (Drive, Interaction, Track, User). 1 best application, 4 worst application.
For example Proband 1 ranked:
Treat 1: 1
Treat 2: 3
Treat 3: 4
Treat 4: 2

My R Script:

```
library(agricolae)
friedman(data$Proband,data$Treatment,data$values, console = T)
```

Output:

```
            data.values  r
Drive                55 27
Interaction          78 27
Track                71 27
User                 66 27

Friedman's Test
===============
Adjusted for ties
Critical Value: 6.244444
P.Value Chisq: 0.1003046
F Value: 2.171819
P.Value F: 0.09801156 

Post Hoc Analysis

Alpha: 0.05 ; DF Error: 78
t-Student: 1.990847
LSD: 18.48986 

Treatments with the same letter are not significantly different.

            Sum of ranks groups
Interaction           78      a
Track                 71     ab
User                  66     ab
Drive                 55      b
```

The output shows that Drive and Interaction are different groups and therefor should differ significantly. On the other hand, the Friedman test itself only has a p-value > 0.05?

(Side question: does the LSD post-hoc test make sense for my ordinal scaled data?)

Why is that the Post-Hoc Analysis significant but the Friedman test is not?

My data:

```
Proband Treatment   values
1   User    4
1   Interaction 3
1   Track   2
1   Drive   1
2   Drive   4
2   Interaction 3
2   Track   2
2   User    1
3   Interaction 4
3   Track   1
3   Drive   2
3   User    3
4   Interaction 3
4   Track   2
4   Drive   4
4   User    1
5   Interaction 1
5   Track   4
5   Drive   2
5   User    3
6   Interaction 3
6   Track   4
6   Drive   1
6   User    2
7   Interaction 4
7   Track   3
7   Drive   1
7   User    2
8   Interaction 4
8   Track   2
8   Drive   1
8   User    3
9   Interaction 3
9   Track   4
9   Drive   1
9   User    2
10  Interaction 4
10  Track   2
10  Drive   1
10  User    3
11  Interaction 2
11  Track   3
11  Drive   4
11  User    1
12  Interaction 1
12  Track   4
12  Drive   3
12  User    2
13  Interaction 4
13  Track   2
13  Drive   1
13  User    3
14  Interaction 3
14  Track   4
14  Drive   2
14  User    1
15  Interaction 4
15  Track   3
15  Drive   1
15  User    2
16  Interaction 4
16  Track   3
16  Drive   1
16  User    2
17  Interaction 3
17  Track   4
17  Drive   1
17  User    2
18  Interaction 1
18  Track   2
18  Drive   4
18  User    3
19  Interaction 3
19  Track   2
19  Drive   1
19  User    4
20  Interaction 4
20  Track   1
20  Drive   2
20  User    3
21  Interaction 3
21  Track   4
21  Drive   2
21  User    1
22  Interaction 1
22  Track   2
22  Drive   3
22  User    4
23  Interaction 3
23  Track   1
23  Drive   2
23  User    4
24  Interaction 4
24  Track   1
24  Drive   2
24  User    3
25  Interaction 4
25  Track   3
25  Drive   1
25  User    2
26  Interaction 1
26  Track   4
26  Drive   3
26  User    2
27  Interaction 1
27  Track   2
27  Drive   4
27  User    3
```

Comment: Neither Wilcoxon nor t test can serve as post hoc for Friedman. Please search here answers on "Friedman post hoc multiple comparisons".

Comment: I should probably delete the part about the pairwise wilcoxon test as it doesn't add any useful information. The friedman() function of the agricolae package uses the LSD Post-Hoc tests. God why is it so complicated to analyze a simple ranked question ;_;

Comment: The correct post hoc test for Friedman's is the Nemenyi's test. However, you should not use it since the Friedman's indicated that there are no significant differences among your treatments.